# Parsing a NSString value from NSDictionary returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, nsdictionary

I am trying to parse the values from an NSDictionary into a local data model.

Here are the contents of the dictionary.

```
Printing description of userProfile:
{
    "created_at" = "2014-01-16T09:08:03.012Z";
    "first_name" = FirstName;
    id = 74;
    "last_name" = LastName;
    phone = 09876543232;
    photo = "<null>";
    "updated_at" = "2014-01-16T12:40:18.143Z";
    "user_id" = 84;
}
```

This is what i use to parse the strings:

```
self.profileId = [[userProfile objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];
self.firstName = (NSString*)[userInfo objectForKey:@"first_name"];
self.lastName = (NSString*)[userInfo objectForKey:@"last_name"];
self.phoneNumber = (NSString*)[userInfo objectForKey:@"phone"];
```

This will return nil on the last three fields. However, if i use this method to parse the data it will actually work.

```
NSArray*keys=[userProfile allKeys];
self.firstName = [userProfile objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:3]];
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: could it be related to a typo? in the first call you retrieve data from the object "userProfile" but in the other three you access the object "userInfo"

Comment: change userInfo to userProfile...

Comment: Can you try `[userInfo objectForKey:@"\"first_name\""]`?

Comment: @rist that was it... i'm such an idiot. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @ C_X Yup... that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing 'userProfile' here

```
self.profileId = [[userProfile objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];
```

but accessing 'userInfo' here

```
self.firstName = (NSString*)[userInfo objectForKey:@"first_name"];
self.lastName = (NSString*)[userInfo objectForKey:@"last_name"];
self.phoneNumber = (NSString*)[userInfo objectForKey:@"phone"];
```

Is this a typo or do you have an object called 'userInfo' that you are mistakenly using?